# Copy number of line composed by special character in bash

Tags: bash

I have an exercise where I have a file and at the begin of it I have something like

```
#!usr/bin/bash



# tototata
#tititutu
#ttta

Hello world
Hi
Test test
#zabdazj
#this is it
```

And I have to take each first line starting with a `#` until the line where I don't have one and stock it in a variable. In case of a shebang, it has to skip it and if there's blank space between lines, it has to skip them too. We just want the comment between the shebang and the next character.
I'm new to bash and I would like to know if there's a way to do it please ?

Expected output:

```
# tototata
#tititutu
#ttta
```

Comment: Provide a minimal input, an expected output along with the attempts you made to solve the problem

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck : But in your case, the expected output should be just the #! line, because it starts with a `#` and the following line does not!

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck : It is also not clear how you are going to deal with those comment lines, where the `#` does not occur in the 1st column, but after some spaces. Right now, the solutions of DamianK and me would treat such lines as stopping conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this easy way to better understand.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 1d your_input_file | while read line; 
do
    check=$( echo $line | grep ^"[#;]" )

    if ([ ! -z "$check" ] || [ -z "$line" ])
    then
            echo $line;
    else
            exit 1;
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `cat` is pointless; just pipe the file into your _while_ loop. Also creating a childprocess running the `echo|grep` pipe is unnecessary. You can check the content of the variable directly in bash.

Comment: And how can I begin the parse at the line 2 of my file ?

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck i modify my example. Now it's start from second line and doesn’t stop when there is a blank line.

Comment: @DamianK : Your change implements the change requested in the comment by the OP, but not the change he sneeked into his question, where it now says: _**In case of** a shebang, it has to skip_. If the script has no sheebang line (which is perfectly legal for sh-scripts), but starts with a comment line, this comment line would be dropped by your code.

Comment: @user1934428 You have right, again :) I just try to help, give answer for specific questions not create complete solution. We don't know how this file will finally looks like. In my opinion it's doesn't matter on this script level.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more correct, although your question was unclear about weather the input file had a script shebang, if the shebang had to be skipped to match your sample output, or if the input file shebang was just bogus.

It is also unclear for what to do, if the first lines of the input file are not starting with `#`.

You should really post your assignment's text as a reference.

Anyway here is a script that does collects first set of consecutive lines starting with a sharp `#` into the `arr` array variable.

It may not be an exact solution to your assignment (witch you should be able to solve with what your previous lessons taught you), but will get you some clues and keys to iterate reading lines from a file and testing that lines starts with a `#`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Our variable to store parsed lines
# Is an array of strings with an entry per line
declare -a arr=()

# Iterate reading lines from the file
# while it matches Regex: ^[#]
# mean while lines starts with a sharp #
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line && [[ "$line" =~ ^[#] ]]; do
  # Add line to the arr array variable
  arr+=("$line")
done <a.txt

# Print each array entries with a newline
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck : If you edit the question in important points (not just fixing errors in language syntax), please ensure that we can see, what parts have been changed/added.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (not tested, so you may have to debug it a bit, but my comments in the code should explain what is going on):

```
while read line
do
  # initial is 1 one the first line, and 0 after this. When the script starts,
  # the variable is undefined.
  : ${initial:=1}
  # Test for lines starting with #. Need to quote the hash
  # so that it is not taken as comment.
  if [[ $line == '#'* ]]
  then
    # Test for initial #!
    if (( initial == 1 )) && [[ $line == '#!'* ]]
    then
      : # ignore it
    else
      echo $line # or do whatever you want to do with it
    fi
  fi
  # stop on non-blank, non-comment line   
  if [[ $line != *[^\ ]* ]]
  then
    break
  fi
  initial=0 # Next line won't be an initial line
done < your_file
```